# QR decomposition in Math.NET Numerics

Tags: mathnet-numerics, qr-decomposition

How is QR decomposition implemented in Math.NET Numerics?

Is it with Gram-Schimdt or with Givens rotations? I have a feeling that it is implemented with Gram-Schimdt, but I'm not sure. I can't find the implementation.

Is QR decomposition with Gram-Schimdt different from with Givens rotations, in terms of results?

I generated (manually) a QR decomposition using Givens rotations for a matrix, and then generated a QR decomposition using`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic.Factorization.QRMethod` (which I believe implements Gram-Schimdt) and the results were slightly different. The difference between numbers is about 1E-16 (not that big), and some rows have the opposite sign (*-1) (this is the real problem - I think this happens because MathNet.Numerics implements a different QR algorithm).

Can you suggest some libraries that perform QR decomposition using Givens rotations?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization/QR%601.htm), it is implemented using [Householder reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_reflection):

> The computation of the QR decomposition is done at construction time
>   by Householder transformation.

Different methods can produce answers with small numerical differences or with negative rows, as you describe.  See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) for more information.